# how to make sure modem is truly in bridge mode

Tags: networking, bridge, pfsense, modem

I need public ip in pfsense wan interface so I configure my adsl modem as bridge mode But I have little doubt on this "**it is truly in bridge mode**".

What are the steps to make sure about bridge mode configure correctly?

according to this [article](http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/110/~/when-to-put-modem-into-bridge-mode?cid=wmt_netgear_organic) when **ifconfig** list private ip address range it is in NAT mode. When I check ifconfig I also get private ip only (**192.168.1.100**) so I am confused.

Comment: Did you configure it to be in bridge mode?

Comment: yes I configured with the help of ISP provider but while cross check I doubt on this...

Comment: Do they use PPPoE?

Comment: basic idea is set modem as bridge mode then connect with pfsense router. I will use pppoe in pfsense wan interface to get public ip. @JuliePelletier

Comment: PPPoE connections do not **require** the modem to be in bridge mode.  The fact that your machine shows a private IP means you're not looking at the PPPoE tunnel adapter.

Comment: yes you are right In modem I do not set pppoe, I set in pfsense router only for getting public ip. before move to pfsense I need to make sure about modem is truely in bridge mode. here modem is combined of (modem+router) ADSL modem

Comment: @BilalUsean Sounds like you answered you're own question. PPPoE modems are just that... you use PPPoE, not ethernet bridging. It will not give you a public IP until PPPoE is connected.

Comment: @RyanBabchishin still I am not connect pfsense router so ignore pppoe concepts. it is just my thought. just consider modem only as bridgemode

Comment: @BilalUsean You can't get a public IP address with a DSL modem that is on a PPPoE network without connecting with PPPoE.

Comment: That's what I meant.  @BilalUsean, how do you expect to get a public IP?

Comment: as your point it is not possible to test bridge mode in modem alone. we need pppoe... am I right? not only ifconfig method any other way to test this. actually raised this question for the purpose of make sure about modem configure correctly otherwise i mess up with any malfunction happen eg. "modem bridge" problem or "pfsense router" problem.

Comment: @BilalUsean:  If you put your modem in bridge mode or want to bypass it, you need to initiate the PPPoE connection in your router.  Once you do, it will show the public IP under its tunnel adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need the read the manual for your modem**

You can often connect to a modem that is in bridge mode following the user manual's instructions to verify it's settings.

Try connecting it to a PC/laptop and if you get the address 192.168.1.100 try connecting to http://192.168.1.1 (my last modem was like that). There might be an admin interface there. Once you get it working this way, then connect it to pfSense.

You could temporarily receive a private address while the modem is working things out with the provider. I've seen that before. But it should change to a public IP shortly after.

**Update:** Since you are using PPPoE - many modems just pass along (pass-through) PPPoE now despite how they are configured, so just try connecting if you think it's setup right. Ignore the fact that it also has a local IP. You can't get a public IP address with a DSL modem that is on a PPPoE network without connecting with PPPoE. Once you connect the modem to pfSense, it will no longer hand out the 192.168.1.100 address because pfSense will not query it with DHCP (unless you setup something funny).

Comment: I got public ip.  modem as bridge mode and then set pppoe in pfsense router. :-)